# Android - Greenrobot EventBus in android?

Tags: android, android-event, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am using from `greenrobot:eventbus` in my project:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

**Problem** :

I am using from `EventBus` for GPS like bellow :

```
public class ConditionGPS {
    public static void statusCheck(Activity activity) {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps(activity);
        } else if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            EventGPS event = new EventGPS();
            event.setGPSMessage(true);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
        }
    }

    private static void buildAlertMessageNoGps(final Activity activity) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.GPS))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.Yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.No), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        EventGPS event = new EventGPS();
                        event.setGPSMessage(false);
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Explain :

In my `setNegativeButton` of alert dialog `EventBus` good work, but I have problem in this section :

```
...
...
else if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                EventGPS event = new EventGPS();
                event.setGPSMessage(true);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
            }
```

I can't get any message in my `activity`.Here is my `activity` :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}

@Subscribe
public void onEvent(EventGPS eventGps) {
    boolean message = eventGps.getGPSMessage();
    if (!message) {
        txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtMessage.setText(getString(R.string.Should));
    }else if (message){
        //****HERE I CAN'T GET ANY MESSAGE****//
        initViews(key);
    }
}
```

And here is my `EventGPS`:

```
public class EventGPS {
    private boolean GPSMessage;

    public boolean getGPSMessage() {
        return GPSMessage;
    }

    public void setGPSMessage(boolean GPSMessage) {
        this.GPSMessage = GPSMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register your activity as receiver.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: @ Denny Weinberg .My problem is not here .

Answer (score 1):

Register your Activity, but make sure you are not already registered or you will get an exception.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
    {  
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```